# Find the number of ways to represent n as a sum of two integers with boundaries

Tags: java, algorithm, nested

I am playing around codefight, but I am really stuck 
to the following efficient issue.

**Problem**:
Given integers n, l and r, find the number of ways to represent n as a sum of two integers A and B such that l ≤ A ≤ B ≤ r.

**Example**:
For n = 6, l = 2 and r = 4, the output should be
countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r) = 2.
There are just two ways to write 6 as A + B, where 2 ≤ A ≤ B ≤ 4: 6 = 2 + 4 and 6 = 3 + 3.

Here is my code. It passes all the unit tests but it failing
in the hidden ones. Can someone direct me somehow?
Thanks in advance.

```
public static int countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(int n, int l, int r) {
    int nrOfWays = 0;
    for(int i=l;i<=r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=r;j++)
        {
            if(i+j==n)
                nrOfWays++;
        }
    }
    return nrOfWays;

}
```

Comment: What are the 'hidden ones'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's no need to make so huge calculations... It's easy to calculate:

```
public static int count(int n, int l, int r) {
    if (l > n/2)
        return 0;
    return Math.min(n/2 - l, r - n/2) + ((n%2 == 1) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Passes all my tests so far. For positives and negatives as well.

Comment: How did you got to this formula? Could you explain?

Comment: @RafaelMiceli Basically these sums are: `n/2 - 1 + n/2 + 1`, `n/2 - 3 + n/2 + 3` ... as long as we hit `l` or `r`. Then if n isn't even we skip `n/2 + n/2`

Comment: This doesn't work for the case where `n=25`, `l=10`, `r=20`. The correct answer is `3`: `(12,13),(11,14),(10,15)`. But this code returns `2`.

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles on this and is wondering about @zambro test case `n=25, l=10, r=20`. Looks like the problem is with the first min arg for odd n, need to add 1 for odd n:
`Math.min((n / 2) + (n % 2) - l, r - (n / 2)) + 1 - (n % 2)`. This solution works for all cases so far.
For clarity, I also added parens, and refactored the `+ ((n%2 == 1) ? 0 : 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

In java:

```
int countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(int n, int l, int r)
{
     return Math.max(0,Math.min(n/2-l,r-n/2)+(n+1)%2);
}
```

In Python3:

```
def countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r):
    return max(0,min(n//2-l,r-n//2)+(n+1)%2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int countSumOfTwoRepresentations(int n, int l, int r)
  {
    int r1 = 0;
    if (n > l + r || n < 2 * l)
        return 0;
    r1 = n - l;
    if ((r1 - l) % 2 == 0)
        return (r1 - l) / 2 + 1;
    else
        return (r1 - l + 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit of explanation along with your answer that explains what was wrong with the original code and what you changed to fix it and why it is that way?

Comment: let A=l then B=n-l. The task be come find number of way to represent n from [A,B]. for example if n=13, l=5, r=17.We have to find Number of way to represent 13 from [5,8], there are [5,8], [6,7]. number of way = ((8-5)+1)/2 it is not difficult to find that rule after you check some another example.

Comment: This doesn't work for the case where n=93, l=24, r=58. The correct answer is 12, but this code returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution using a hash table. No as efficient as the others, but easier to understand. Based on the famous leetcode "2sum" problem.

https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

```
fun solution(n: Int, l: Int, r: Int): Int {
    
    val h = hashMapOf<Int, Int>()
    for (i in l..r)
    {
        val c = n-i
        if (c >=l && c<=r)
        {
            if (h[i] == null)
            {
                h.put(c, i)
            }
        }
    }
    
    return h.size
}
```