# Count Sum Of Representation

Tags: java

Given integers n, l and r, find the number of ways to represent n as a sum of two integers A and B such that l ≤ A ≤ B ≤ r.

Example

For n = 6, l = 2 and r = 4, the output should be

```
countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(n, l, r) = 2.
```

There are just two ways to write 6 as A + B, where 2 ≤ A ≤ B ≤ 4: 6 = 2 + 4 and 6 = 3 + 3.

Solution:

```
int countSumOfTwoRepresentations2(int n, int l, int r)
{
    int count = 0;
    int n1 = l;
    int n2 = r;

    while (n1 <= n2) {
        while (n1 <= n2) {
            if (n1 + n2 == n) {
                count++;
            }
            n2--;
        }
        n1++;
        n2 = r;
    }

    return count;
}
```

This solution takes too much time for execution due to 2 while loops. Whether anyone suggest better solution for that or what modification should I make to my code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not sure how long of execution time is considered slow, on my machine ran in 155 µs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the number of ways to represent n as a sum of two integers with boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860021/find-the-number-of-ways-to-represent-n-as-a-sum-of-two-integers-with-boundaries)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can calculate with the equation. note l is letter el.

```
x = int((n-l)/2)

if(!(n%2) && (n-l)%2)
{
   x = x + 1
}
```

Comment: seems need to be adjusted according to whether or not n is even.

Comment: this is based on the idea that l can only take the values from l up to the middle of the range between l and r (r = n - l).